# jQuery DataTable Column RenderLinkAsButton in C# ASP.NET MVC Project?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, button, datatables

I am replacing a jQuery DataTable that performs client side processing. I would like to add a Details column, such as the following:

[image]

When one of the Details buttons is clicked, the Details View for that particular record is opened.

The following is the code that used to accomplish this:

```
<td class="action-button-column">@Html.RenderLinkAsButton(ButtonTypes.View, Url.Action("Details", "Controller", new {id = model.Id, area = "Area"}), Enums.ButtonSize.Small)</td>
```

Can I use/add RenderLinkAsButton in a DataTable column?

I know that I can use the following code to create a button that will perform the same thing:

```
columns: [
                {
                    data: "Id",
                    title: "Details",
                    render: function (data) {
                        var myUrl = '@Url.Action("Details", "Controller")?Id=' + data;
                        return '<a href=\"' + myUrl + '\" class=\"btn btn-info\"></a>';
                    }
                }
         ]
```

However, I would like to include the icon, in this case an opened folder, to be consistent with other Index Views that use client side processing DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add the following with a leading space: `fa-folder-open`

```
columns: [
                {
                    data: "Id",
                    title: "Details",
                    render: function (data) {
                        var myUrl = '@Url.Action("Details", "Controller")?Id=' + data;
                        return '<a href=\"' + myUrl + '\" class=\"btn btn-info\ fa fa-folder-open"></a>';
                    }
                }
         ]
```